# How to rewrite a jump link with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have rewrites in an htaccess file of mine and need to account for a jumplink.

The issue I beleive I am having is the '#' keeps getting recognized as a comment.

I've seen questions on here suggesting the use of the [NE] or [R] flags, but either I am not using them correctly or they do not do what I need.

My current working rewrite is:

`RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/*$ display_news.php?yid=$1&mid=$2 [L]`

My idea was to append another segment to the end of the url with something like this:

`RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/1/*$ display_news.php?yid=$1&mid=$2#jumplink [L]`

With my use of the [NE] and [R] flags I replaced `?` with `3F` and `$` with `24` for hexcodes given by http://www.asciitable.com/.  Do I have to enclose these codes with special brackets or something?  How would Apache know I don't literally mean `3F` or `24`.

The current behavior when I try to place these hexcodes in my file I get the internal server error.

If there is a more elegant method to account for jumplinks in an htaccess file I am all ears.

EDIT:

As suggested here are example URLs of what I am expecting.

`http://website.com/news/2013/11` would map to `display_news.php?yid=2013&mid=11`

and

`http://website.com/news/2013/11/1` would map to `display_news.php?yid=2013&mid=11#jumplink`

But I would want the address to remain in the format `http://website.com/news/2013/11/1` and just map to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/1/?$ /display_news.php?yid=$1&mid=$2#jumplink [L,NC,QSA,NE,R=302]
```

I suggest you to provide example of URIs that you want to match and what what is your target URI.

Comment: The above seems to append the server path to the domain of my site and change the address in the URL bar.  Something like `http://website.com/var/www/website.com/display_news.php?yid=2013&mid=09#revisit`

Comment: Okay, so with the `[R=302]` it shows my the URL being exactly what I wanted.  For some reason it doesn't seem to be Jumping to the portion of the page in which I have the `<a id="jumplink"></a>` though.  This is probably getting into something outside of the scope of my original question though.

Comment: I would believe if page has `jumplink` tags properly defined then that portion should automatically scroll up.

Answer (score 1):

The `#jumplink` part of the URI that you've rewritten to is completely meaningless to the server. The URL fragment (the `#jumplink` part) is used by browsers and javascript running on browsers. It's not even passed to php.

You can try adding an `R` flag to externally redirect the browser but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to jump to a certain portion of the page.  I'm not trying to access the `#jumplink` by server side code at all.

Comment: @d.lanza38 You're going to have to do something on the browser's side then. Maybe use some javascript to see what the location is, and if it's missing the `#` then add it.

Comment: I may be missing something then, don't browsers innately support the functionality of #jumplink when it is appended to the URL?  Mod rewrites aside I know if you have an anchor tag with `id="jumplink"` and you append `#jumplink` to the URL it will automatically load the page to where ever that anchor tag is.  I am just trying to do the same but I don't know how to override the default behavior of `#` in the htaccess file (which is a comment).  It seems a simple `\#` does not do the trick.

Comment: @d.lanza38 when you use rewites the URL is changed *only* on the server, the browser still thinks it sees `/news/blah/blah/1/`. It doesn't even know the fragment is there. On the server's end, the server doesn't even care about the fragment, it's got no use for it, so the internal rewrite does nothing about the fragment. Also, htaccess comments are only when `#` is at the start of a line.

Comment: Ahh, and that explains why after successfully rewriting the URL to what I wanted I did not get my expected result.  Figures, I try to do something quick and dirty and that's what I get.  Thank you.